# Creating queries in SQL that involve math

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to *"Produce a query to display the branch names and total number of jobs of the two branches with the fewest total number of jobs. The branch that an accountant works at determines which jobs are associated with which branch."*

This is my attempt to answer:

```
SELECT TOP 2 b.branchName, SUM(j.job_id) 
  FROM branch AS b 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j
    ON b.branch_id - b.branch_id
 ORDER BY sum(j.job_id);
```

I am getting an error

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 129 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context
where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'
```

Comment: I'm going to guess SQL Server, can you confirm?

Comment: What output does your query give? What would be the correct output?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: yes its an SQL server 

i get this result 
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 129
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'.

Comment: unfortunately im not sure what DBMS im using

Comment: expected result,with sample i/p tables with data would be useful to get wat you askin ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question so I will not give a working example but rather try to explain some issues with your current query.

The error you get

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 129 An expression of non-boolean type specified 
in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'
```

is because the `ON` clause expects an expression that evaluates to a `boolean`. The expression you are currently using will presumably evaluate to an `int`

this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j
  ON b.branch_id - b.branch_id   -- i.e  5 - 3 := 2
```

should be

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN job AS j
  ON b.branch_id = b.branch_id   -- i.e. 5 = 3 := false
```

Taking the `sum()` of IDs doesn't make sense

```
BranchId | JobId
----------------   
1        | 1     --|
1        | 2       | sum(JobId) is 6 
1        | 3     --|

2        | 2     --|
2        | 3       | sum(JobId) is 9
2        | 4     --|
```

what you most likely want is a `count()`

```
BranchId | JobId
----------------   
1        | 1     --|
1        | 2       | count(JobId) is 3
1        | 3     --|

2        | 2     --|
2        | 3       | count(JobId) is 3
2        | 4     --|
```

You are missing the `group by` clause

[`TOP n`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) will only return the first `n` results and doesn't take into consideration when records are tied, for this you can use the `WITH TIES` clause.

Comment: thankyou for the advice, it cleared up a lot of confusion  
i will keep working at it